# How to troubleshoot 'Visual Studio is Busy' issues? Visual Studio never recovers

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I get this 'Visual Studio is busy' message often when I try to do anything in it. This happens in different situations. It can happen when VS starts before loading any solution. It can happen after loading a solution. I just upgraded today to 17.3.6 and it happened again. I have already reinstalled VS. I did a repair. I did a 'devenv /resetsettings', 'devenv /resetuserdata'. 'devenv /setup'. Deleted %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\              \ComponentModelCache.

I did devenv.exe /log `<path>` and I didn't see anything glaring in the log.

I have a handful of extensions but haven't gone through disabling them and using VS without them. I need them for my work.

Once I get this message, there's nothing I can do but kill the process because VS never recovers from it. I am not seeing any pattern as to what might cause the issue and it seems it's random. I just have to keep killing and relaunching VS until I get a good instance (1-5 times).
Because it's random, I can't determine if anything I did from the above steps helps because VS can launch just fine sometimes.

I also recently changed the setting to not participate in the VS experience improvement program so that PerfWatson2 doesn't launch.

Any ideas on how to find the cause of this issue?

[image]

Comment: Few months old thread here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-studio-2022-freezes---Visual-Stu/1659233 But I have a feeling it's probably machine specific.  Do you have a spare machine to install it on to try it out? Or a coworker/friend who can try?  Also I believe it is now possible to rollback versions of Visual Studio using the installer.  Perhaps try that as well.

Comment: It happens on my work and home computers. My VS installations went through many updates over time and this busy issue is not new. I can't remember which version this issue started happening.